# Adding a column string to a list for each selected Row in a DataGridVIew

Tags: c#

I want to add the 'OrderID' in the below DataGridView to a list for each row that I select.

[image]

I have managed to get it to cycle through a foreach loop but I am trying to figure out how to specify the selected row index, as it currently pulls the same indexed 'OrderID' and not the different ones selected.
See result I am currently getting:

[image]

See current code:

```
  List<string> orders = new List<string>();
      foreach (var row in grid.SelectedRows)
      {
        orders.Add(grid.Rows[grid.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
      }
```

I know I shouldn't be using SelectedRows[0], but I cant think of how to index the specific 'row'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a for loop instead:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < grid.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
      {
        orders.Add((grid.Rows[i].Cells["Order ID"].Value).ToString());
      }
```